# Correct notation for getting a random value from a random variable

Tags: probability, random-variable

Suppose that I want to generate a single random value from a random variable $X$ and store it in a variable $a$. What is the correct notation to describe this? I don't think $a = X$ will work. To put it in other words, in Python this can be done as follows (for a standard normal variable):

```
a = np.random.normal()
```

What is the equivalent of the above assignment in mathematical notation?

Comment: @AryaMcCarthy $a$ is a realisation while $X$ is a random variable, so I do not think the notation $a\sim X$ applies. The event $\{\omega;\ X(\omega)=a\}$ occurred.

Comment: The Python analogy does not help much as the random generators like `np.random.normal` are pseudo-random and deterministic functions of the random seed variable.

Comment: @AryaMcCarthy: sorry to insist but the issue is the same, $a$ is a realisation, to be distinguished from the random variable.

Comment: @AryaMcCarthy doesn't $a \sim \mathcal{N}(0,1)$ mean $a$ is distributed normally?

Comment: As already commented $a$ is a realization of the real random variable $X$. A real random variable is a measurable function $X:\Omega \rightarrow R$, and $a$ is the output of that mapping i.e $X(\omega)=a$

Comment: Your out of luck! **Assignment is not a mathematical concept at all** so there is no mathematical notation for it. Mathematical variables have values that never change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you have to specify what distribution you are drawing the the variable from, e.g. $\mathcal{N}(0, 1)$. Then, denote the variable by a letter, typically a capital one, like $X$. Finally, you can say $X \sim \mathcal{N}(0, 1)$.

PS: your question deals with the concept of "realization" of random variable.

Referring to this[1], you can say "$a$ is a realization of random variable $X$". If you want to denote it mathematically: $a = X(\omega)$ for some $\omega \in \Omega$, where $\Omega$ is the sample space of X.

[1]: Taboga, Marco (2017). "Realization of a random variable", Lectures on probability theory and mathematical statistics, Third edition. Kindle Direct Publishing. Online appendix. https://www.statlect.com/glossary/realization-of-a-random-variable.

Comment: The difficulty is not that your question is 'somewhat different' from what you see in reasonable answers. The difficulty is that your question is quite unclear. // The use of $x$ for a particular realization of a random variable $X$ (as in the link in this Ans) is well-established. // If you are using software such as Python or R, then you will have to use notation that follows the rules of the software. In R, you could use `x = rnorm(1, 100, 15)`, but you'd have to remember that `x` and `X` are names of different objects in R. (Use comments following `#`s to explain what you're doing.)

Comment: @BruceET You did not say what is quite unclear in my question.

Comment: It might have been better to make it clear you are taking an observation or a sample from a distribution. Also some information about your convention in using upper and lower case letters for random variables would have helped. Introducing the use of Python or other computer programs into a discussion of math notation can lead to confusion. // For me, your comment challenging @Sobir's answer added to the confusion--especially in view of the excellent link provided.

Comment: @BruceET Sobir's answer was only the first paragraph (the part before the PS) when I wrote my comment, s/he updated the answer after my comment, then I accepted the answer, and now I will delete my comment not to create more confusion. And thank you for your reply.

Comment: @SanyoMn sorry about that, I should have mentioned my update to the answer in the comments.