# Use of lowercase letters for random variables in machine learning

Tags: machine-learning, notation

In statistics/probability, a random sample from a distribution $D$ is a set of i.i.d. random variables denoted by $X_1, X_2, \dots, X_n$, each with distribution $D$. A realization of a random sample is a set of values denoted by $x_1, x_2, \dots, x_n$. Here the important point is the convention to use uppercase letters for random variables and lowercase letters for realizations. However, in machine learning texts, I see the use of lowercase letters to denote a random sample from a distribution (which happens to be the dataset). For example, Andrew Ng uses lowercase letters [here](http://cs229.stanford.edu/notes2020spring/cs229-notes7b.pdf) to denote random samples and, moreover, he uses $x^{(i)} \sim \mathcal{N}(\mu,\,\sigma^{2})$, that is, uses a lowercase letter, $x$, for describing the associated distribution for a random variable. I can give examples from other authors. Is this a common practice for machine learning researchers? And if it is a common convention, is there some reason why ML researchers use a different notation given that there is an established convention in statistics/probability? That really creates confusion (at least for me).

Comment: You've written that you can find examples from other authors, and then ask whether this notation is common practice for machine learning researchers. Can you clarify what kind of information you're looking for in an answer? Why are examples of other researchers using notation in this way not sufficient to answer your question, and what kind of additional information would satisfy your query?

Comment: This (and all notation really) is largely based on the field and context.  I have seen lower vs upper case mean all kinds of things like vector vs matrix.  You typically have to deduce what's going on unless it is explicit.

Comment: @Sycorax let me clarify, is there some reason why ML researchers use a different notation given that there is an established convention in statistics/probability? It really confuses me.

Comment: Perhaps you could [edit] your question to clarify that you're not asking whether or not this is common practice, but instead asking if there is a particular reason to use this notation.

Comment: Actually I'm asking both since I'm not sure whether it is a common convention in ML, I will edit my answer.

Comment: Ok, it's perfectly fine to ask both of those questions, but you haven't answered my question. Why are examples of other researchers using this notation not sufficient to answer the question about whether or not it is common? If that's not an answer, then what does count as an answer about how common it is to use notation that way?

Comment: @Sycorax My list of other researchers is not definitive, maybe some use this way some others use in another way, I'm wondering whether there is some general consensus on this in ML community.

Comment: Yes, I know that's what you're asking. I want to know how you would decide whether an an answer is definitive or not.

Comment: An answer like this "Yes it is a common convention in ML and the reason is ..."

Comment: That doesn't answer my question because it doesn't tell me what "definitive" means to you. "Yes, this is a common convention, and the reason is it's used in published research, here's an example of research that contains it." This is trivially the only way to answer it, an this is something you already know because you've found the research that uses that notation.

Comment: So you say that there is no other reason than being used by researchers?

Comment: I'm not speaking to the **reason**, I'm solely trying to understand how a person is supposed to answer the "is this notation common?" portion of your question. I'm trying to avoid a situation where someone writes an answer that says "It's common because here are several examples of this notation in published literature" and then you say "I know that there are some examples, but I'm asking for a definitive answer," but you never explicitly state what "definitive" means so no one knows how to answer the question.

Comment: @Sycorax. I believe the motivation for this question might make more sense with the inclusion of this previously asked question by OP:

https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/522499/correct-notation-for-getting-a-random-value-from-a-random-variable

And I think the aporia that the OP is attempting to allude to is why given in that previous post it is established that examples of notation used by ML researchers is 'imprecise' from a mathematical probabilist's perspective, the 'imprecise' notation continues to be used.

Comment: My knowledge of several examples does not enough to conclude that it is a common practice in ML. But the confirmation of an expert person will increase my belief that it is indeed the case and I'm not misunderstanding something

Comment: In any case the 'aporia' is resolved by sufficient attention to context, and sensitivity to the conventions of the subfield the particular text in question locates itself within. In the sense that the relevant notation might be used in ML research as a convention, but probabilists would see it as an aberration.

Comment: @microhaus That's helpful context, and perhaps related to this question. If your guess is correct and that is what OP would like to ask about, then OP should [edit] the question to make that clear.

Comment: What is the guess of @microhaus?